# SelectionSort Template function not working with arrays

Tags: c++, c++11, selection-sort, function-templates

I have a template function that performs an index-based selection sort on an indexable object. The IndexedContainer must support `operator[]` and `size()`, e.g. `std::vector`. Container elements must support `operator<` and `operator=`.

My function must take in any std::vector or array and sort it in ascending order.

Function works but only for vectors since I'm using the size() function. I'm having trouble supporting the operator[] in my function since the size() function does not work for arrays.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename IndexedContainer>
void SelectionSort(IndexedContainer &values) {
    // TODO
    int temp;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++){
        for(unsigned int j = i; j > 0; j--){
            if(values[j] < values[j-1]){
                temp = values[j];
                values[j] = values[j-1];
                values[j-1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<char> data = {'a','4','b','2','c','1'};
    std::vector<int> data3 = {1,5,6,8,10,2};
    //std::vector<std::string> data4 = {"1d23","3v4f","0878"};
    char data2[] = "a3b4c1d2";
    SelectionSort(data);
    SelectionSort(data2);
    SelectionSort(data3);
    for(auto i: data){
        std::cout<<i<<" ";
    }
    std::cout<<'\n';
    std::cout<<data2<<'\n';

    for(auto j: data3){
        std::cout<<j<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: An alternative to size() could be to use iterators or pointers similar to what the STL is doing. Functions receive iterators for the first element and the element next to the last element. This would also be possible for arrays.

Comment: Another option is to create your own template function `ContainerSize` or similar that uses `.size()` by default, but you then specialize it for `const char*` such that it calls `strlen` instead.

Comment: As a side note, use `std::swap` to exchange elements, rather than coding it manually.  This will use the correct types.  What you have right now assumes everything is `int`.  If you _insist_ on doing it manually, use `decltype(values[0]) temp;` instead.

Comment: Standard library algorithms do not operate on containers. There might be a good reason for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

c++17 introduces [`std::size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size), a free function that encapsulates size for things with the `size` member function and arrays. If you don't have c++17, conveniently that link includes an implementation. The crux of which is this specialisation:

```
template <class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t size(const T (&array)[N]) noexcept
{
    return N;
}
```

Copy that, and use `size` free function in your implementation.

Comment: This is perfect, but I'm limited on only have this one function. Is there another way to get the size of either array or vector without the need of another function?

Comment: Add the same template arguments to the function and use this logic directly with template specializations.